# how to delete annotation in Seaborn (live)heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to make live stock heatmap, which updates it's data every 0.2 seconds with stock ticker/price annotations on it. But when I started code for first time, i found that Seaborn puts another annotations without deleting the previous one every time it is called. Can someone tell me how to delete previous annotation or edit already existing annotations?

```
def animate(i):
    #getting price datas from sql
    mkdatac.execute(stc, (chs,))
    pricerows = mkdatac.fetchall()
    for row in pricerows:
        prices = (np.asarray(pricerows).reshape(1, 2))
        print(prices)
    mkdatac.execute(stt, (chs,))
    stcoderows = mkdatac.fetchall()
    for row in stcoderows:
        symbols = (np.asarray(stcoderows).reshape(1, 2))
        print(symbols)
    
    #making labels(annotation)
    labels = (np.asarray(["{0} \n {1:.2f}".format(symb,value)
                          for symb, value in zip(symbols.flatten(),
                                                 prices.flatten())])
              ).reshape(1,2)

    #drawing heatmap
    sns.heatmap(prices, annot=labels, fmt="", cmap='RdYlGn', linewidths=0.30, ax=ax, cbar=False)
```

Comment: You need `ax.cla()` to prevent the memory getting full quite rapidly.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works like what i intended:)